# .net object is not accessable to .html file in wpf application

Tags: javascript, .net, wpf, binding, cefsharp

I'm trying to bind .net object to javascript code in wpf application using cefsharf library

**.net code**

```
 webBrowser.JavascriptobjectRepository.Registry("jsobject",new 
  BoundObject(),true);
  webBrowser.IsBrowserInitializedChanged += 
  browser_IsBrowserInitializedChanged();
  webBrowser.LoadingStateChanged += browser_LoadingStateChanged();

  public class BoundObject
  {
  public string AppId()
  { return "Id"}

  public string AppCode()
  { return "Code"}
  }
```

**xamlcode**

```
  `<cef:chromiumwWebbrowser x:name"webBrowser"/>`
```

**javascriptcode in html file**

```
   `(async function(){
    await cefsharp.BindObjectAsync("jsobject");
    objappid = jsobject.AppId();
    objappid = jsobject.AppCode();
    })();`
```

in html page getting error -> uncaught(in promise)Reference error: cefsharp is not defined

basically i am not able to fetch .net object methods(AppId and AppCode) in javascript code

I tried different things to bind like

```
`webBrowser.JavascriptobjectRepository.Resolveobject +=(sender,e)=>
{

// trying to register object here
}`
```

for everything getting same error

Comment: _cefsharp is not defined_ - where is `cefsharp` defined? Try `window.jsobject.AppId()`.

Comment: "cefsharp" I do not know to define it in javascript code couldn't find cefsharp.js file in my solution.
i tried your solution getting error -> uncaught(in promise) typeError :cannot read properties of undefined(reading 'AppId')

Comment: If you don't know what `cefsharp` is, why do you write `await cefsharp.BindObjectAsync("jsobject")`?

Comment: i know what is cefsharp and my code was working before.. suddenly it started giving error now i am not understanding how to fix it ..

earlier javascript code was able to fetch .net object method with same code, now all of the sudden its asking to define cefsharp in javascript

Comment: Have you tried to access as I wrote `window.jsobject.AppId()`?

Comment: yes,  getting error -> uncaught(in promise) typeError :cannot read properties of undefined(reading 'AppId')

Comment: When/where do you call ` webBrowser.JavascriptobjectRepository.Registry(...`, is it before html page is loaded?

Comment: if you see my code first i will register object, then below method browser_IsBrowserInitializedChanged() will load html page

Answer (score 0):

First I'd suggest you read the [Wiki](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#binding-an-async-object-in-javascript) which has more detail/examples. The [JavaScript API](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/JavaScript-Binding-API) that `CefSharp` exposes is also available on the wiki for reference.

Your code is full of mistakes, won't compile, so it's not clear that it's the actual code you are using. Both `c#` and `JavaScript` are case sensitive. You need to make sure your calls match those.

```cs
webBrowser.JavascriptObjectRepository.Register("jsobject", new BoundObject(), true);
```

```js
(async function()
{
    // Case is important
    await CefSharp.BindObjectAsync("jsobject");
    
    //The default is to camel case method names (the first letter of the method name is changed to lowercase)
    const appId = await jsobject.appId();
    const appCode = await jsobject.appCode();
})();
```

Comment: Getting same errror with await CefSharp.BindObjectAsync("jsobject"); -> uncaught(in promise)Reference error: cefsharp is not defined.....its a run time errror and compile is working fine......In c# class AppId() and AppCode() is the method name not appId/appCode.....c# object is getting created before accessing it in js code..I had already referred the link you shared before.

Comment: By default method names are converted to `camelCase` in `javascript`. If you are getting the error `cefsharp is not defined` then that's an error in your code, as the name should be `CefSharp` (case sensitive as I've already pointed out).